# Ocaml, understand a function

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have some problems in understanding how this function works, 
in particular I' don't understand the control flow of itregarding the last line.
Can someone explain me the steps it does, maybe with a pseudocode?

```
    let traduit_pair a b =
            let a = traduit mark a in let b = traduit mark b in (a, b) in
    let (teq1, teq2, lneq) =
            let rec f l1 l2 l3 =
            (function
                 | [] -> ((Uplet l1), (Uplet l2), l3)
                 | EqualIF (a, b) :: fin ->
                     let (a, b) = traduit_pair a b
                     in f (a :: l1) (b :: l2) l3 fin
                 | NotEqualIF (a, b) :: fin ->
                         let (a, b) = traduit_pair a b
                     in f l1 l2 ((a, b) :: l3) fin)
            in f [] [] [] (List.rev condlst)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the control flow of it regarding the last line". The last line just calls the function `f` which has been defined on the lines preceding it.

Comment: I want say the control flow of the entire function, I don't understand why there are four arguments in the last line and what are the return values. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The function f is called to assign value to the tuple (teq1,teq2, lneq)?

Comment: Yes. Or more specifically: f is called and returns a tuple containing three values and those three values are then assigned to the variables `teq1`, `teq2` and `lneq` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The general flow of your code is like this:

First the function `traduit_pair` is defined. It takes two arguments `a` and `b` and returns a pair containing the result of applying `traduit mark` to each of them.

Then the variables `teq1`, `teq2` and `lneq` are defined to each contain one element of the triple returned by `f [] [] [] (List.rev condlst)`, where `f` is defined as follows:

First of all let's look at why `f` can be called with four arguments when its definition only names three arguments: As you probably know ML allows curried function definitions and the definition `let f x y = blabla` is really just a shortcut for `let f = fun x => fun y => blabla`.

So when we talk about a function taking two arguments, we're really talking about a function taking one argument and returning another function which takes another argument. Likewise a function which takes three arguments and then returns another function taking another argument, is the same thing as a function taking four arguments.

The `function` keyword which is used in the definition of `f` is a syntactic shortcut to create a function taking an argument and pattern matching on it. That is to say `function | p1 -> e1 | p2 -> e2` is a shortcut for `fun x => case x of | p1 -> e1 | p2 -> e2`. So `let rec f l1 l2 l3 = function | p1 -> e1 | p2 -> e2` is the same as `let rec f l1 l2 l3 = fun l4 => case l4 of | p1 -> e1 | p2 -> e2`, which is the same as `let rec f l1 l2 l3 l4 = case l4 of | p1 -> e1 | p2 -> e2`, which is easily identifiable as a function taking four arguments.